# Bash script check time differnce between two directory

Tags: bash

I am looking for a bash script to who check time difference between two directory? But in $oldtime i can`t get only 20:09:24 i get this "20:09:24.660157390".
How can i get only hours:min only.

```
#!/bin/bash



oldtime=$(stat -c %y /mnt/dir1| awk '{print $2}' )
ctime=$(date | awk '{print $4}')


DIFF=$($oldtime-$ctime)
if [ $DIFF > 600 ]; then
    echo "This directory have more that 10 min"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* shave off the extra suffix,
but that won't really help you.
`20:09:24 - $ctime` is not going to work,
because "20:09:24" is not a number.
You have several other syntax errors as well.

To calculate the difference between dates,
you need to work with seconds.

```
oldseconds=$(stat -c %Y /mnt/dir1)
newseconds=$(date +%s)

if (((newseconds - oldseconds) / 60)); then
    echo "This directory have more than 10 min"
fi
```

Comment: Add ")" after "DIFF=$(((newseconds - oldseconds) / 60)" and work perfect. Tnk

Comment: @user8826215 well spotted! On a second look, I improved on it, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use epoch timestamp and date for converting to that format.

```
$ date +%H:%M -d @`stat -c %Y /tmp/`
19:19
```

But it's not recommended to use this format for comparing. Use unix timestamps instead:

```
if [ $(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y /tmp) )) -gt 600 ]; then
    echo "This directory have more that 10 min"
fi
```